# Hex Color codes maybe causing CSS to not work

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: ffe750;
}

#background {
    background-color: fc5f50;
}
```

In the html file I just have the div mentioned above, when I load the page, the colors aren't displaying (I got the Hex values from photoshop). I would just like to display two different colors on each half.

---

**EDIT**

Sorry for my ignorance, it was a very silly mistake, sadly I can't delete the question, very sorry.

Comment: `ffe750` -> `#ffe750` - you could've easily figured this by looking at *any* reference for the `background` or `background-color` property.

Comment: what a silly mistake, I will delete the question right now, thank you very much @domdom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lack `#`:

```
body {
    background-color: #ffe750;
}

#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fc5f50;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a silly mistake though, sorry for bothering you